# SQL Query to generate Employee absent report for a given range of dates

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I Have two tables Master(empname,empid) which consists of all the employees and another table Transaction(empid,Presentdate) which gives the dates and which employee was present.
How do i find the list of absentees within a certain range of dates

I've tried the below Sql Query

```
SELECT empid FROM Master 
where empid NOT IN(select empid  from  Transaction 
where Date(Presentdate) between '2012-11-21' and '2012-12-22')
```

which returns only the employee  id's who were absent,I want to display the employee's absent dates also

Note(Transaction table stores only the employee's present dates)

**If an employee is absent then Entire record will not be inserted into the Transaction table**

Comment: How can you do this? U should have absent date right? Are you having any business rules?

Comment: I think you two options. 1) write some store procedure 2) you need get the result from above query and do some coding in PHP.

Comment: @Mari I'm not sure,but I think can we take the absent dates from a given date range?for example if a date range is 5 .In that 3 dates are present in the Transaction table ,then remaining 2 dates we consider as absent dates?

Comment: so can we assume that emp_id's are arranged in an order. So that we can get the absent date from nearest employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, untested

```
SELECT m.empid     AS `Empid` 
     , d.dt        AS `AbsentDate`
  FROM ( SELECT DATE(t.Presentdate) AS dt
           FROM transaction t
          WHERE t.Presentdate >= '2012-11-21' 
            AND t.Presentdate < DATE_ADD( '2012-12-22' ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          GROUP BY DATE(t.Presentdate)
          ORDER BY DATE(t.Presentdate)
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN master m
  LEFT
  JOIN  transaction p
    ON p.Presentdate >= d.dt
   AND p.Presentdate <  d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND p.empid = m.empid
 WHERE p.empid IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY m.empid
     , d.dt
```

Comment: what is 'd' in your query?

Comment: The inline view aliased as `d` gets us a set of "date" values that we are checking. Using the transaction table as a source of these "date" values is a convenient way to do this. Basically, what we are after is a distinct set of DATE values between the two values passed in as arguments.

Comment: This solution might have a problem. If you have a day when all employees are absent (which can happen on public holidays). I would create a separate table [Dates] with a record for each date independently from the data stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this, but this might work:

```
SELECT m.empid,d.Presentdate

FROM Master as m,
(select distinct Presentdate from transaction
where Date(Presentdate) between '2012-11-21' and '2012-12-22') as d 

where m.empid not in (select empid  from  Transaction 
where Presentdate=d.Presentdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

// i suppose your query will like this to get employee name, id and day in which he/she is present.

```
select empid,empname,date  from  Transaction LEFT JOIN Master ON empid 
where Date(Presentdate) between '2012-11-21' and '2012-12-22'
```

// for looping purpose created an array. You will be having emp id and name also

```
$array = array('2012-01-01','2012-01-02','2012-01-03','2012-01-05'); 
$date = new DateTime('2012-01-01'); // take first as start date
$startDate = $array[0]; 
$endDate = $array[count($array)-1];
$loop = 'yes';

while($loop == 'yes') {
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));    //add one day to start date
    if(!in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'),$array))
        $absentDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    if($date->format('Y-m-d') == $endDate)
        $loop = 'no';
}
print_r($absentDate);
```